# jQuery - add bootstrap dropdown classes to existing UL LI menu structure

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu, traversal

I think my issue can be solved with jQuery.

**Situation:**

I have a certain CMS (photostore script). It has a categories menu item. Categories can be added by users, and moved and deleted by admins. So, the structure and hierarchy is changing. The output results in a cascading UL/LI. I can't and won't change any core PHP file, so I guess parsing the UL/LI, and adding the necessary bootstrap CSS classes is a good alternative. Does it make sense?

**Hint:**

The main nav is a UL/LI itself! This main nav includes 3 UL/LI submenu items. The following category UL is one of them. It has no special class, nor an ID! The other two submenus should not be harmed/touched.

A core sample category menu structure looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/category/nature.html" title="Nature">Nature</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/category/animals.html" title="Animals">Animals</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/category/birds.html" title="Birds">Birds</a></li>
        <li><a href="/category/cats.html" title="Cats">Cats</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/category/test.html" title="Test">Test</a></li>
<li><a href="/category/cities.html" title="Cities">Cities</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/category/architecture.html" title="Architecture">Architecture</a</li>
      <li><a href="/category/firenze.html" title="Firenze">Firenze</a></li>
      <li><a href="/category/venezia.html" title="Venezia">Venezia</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/category/movies.html" title="Movies">Movies</a></li>
<li><a href="/category/sounds.html" title="Sounds">Sounds</a></li>
<li><a href="/category/illustrations.html" title="Illustrations">Illustrations</a>
    <ul>
<li><a href="/category/vector.html" title="Vector">Vector</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/category/misc.html" title="Misc">Misc</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to apply the Bootstrap CSS classes on client side? Even on the dynamic structure? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns

**Idea 1 and task:**

I would need this class on the FIRST UL only. Important to add it on FIRST, because the core script uses a single UL in output routine.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
```

If a SUBcategory LI contains a new UL … it just needs:

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
```

It seems the bootstrap submenu needs an additional link (a-tag). Inserted before the UL submenu.

The bootstrap sample structure looks like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  ...
  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Idea 2 and task:**

If idea 1 is to complex or un-predictable. It should work with a simpler solution. Just 1 level and the drop-down-effect. So, the whole menu shows-up as an unfolded tree.

Answer (score 2):

Changing bootstrap menu to sample ul li menu

```
 $('ul li:has(ul)').addClass('dropdown');
 $('ul li:has(ul) ul').addClass('dropdown-menu');
 $('ul li a:has(ul)').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
 $(".dropdown a").attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
 $(".dropdown-menu a").removeAttr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on client side without any problems. For example:

```
$(function(){        

    $("ul").addClass("dropdown-menu");    

    var menu = $("ul").first()               
            .attr("role", "menu")
            .attr("aria-labelledby", "dropdownMenu")

    $("a").attr("tabindex", "-1");    

    $("li").has("ul").addClass("dropdown-submenu");   

    $("<div/>").addClass("dropdown clearfix").appendTo("body").append($(menu));

});
```

See working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMY5g/3/)

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution. Almost suitable...
It seems I have one more issue with the planned main menu bar. It includes OTHER drop-down menus! Currently there are two other items that are build in another PHP file. Those menus are already done. They also have different webfont icons.

How would i target this particular category UL list ?

Comment: What is the last line and the DIV doing?

Comment: It's just a wrapping element. Details in your bootstrap URL about dropdowns. Could you show final version of your menu?

Comment: Final version: Not yet, the first beta still has its old ddsmoothmenu. I am going to replace the complete header section incl. the menu. Still on my local server environment. Regarding the extra DIV: I don´t have this. My menu is at first level a UL/LI. Some of the LI will have a DropDown menu. Only one of them is the mentioned CATEGORY structure. So, I have to alter this particular CATEGORY menu. But how? I have searched and read about "nth child" and (el). I also tried some given examples in jsFiddle. It does not work reliable with my cascading UL/LI.

Comment: Should I edit my initial question? Or add my second part of my issue? The additional related question is: How to target my mentioned category UL in my main nav UL/LI structure ? It has no class or ID. It is 1 of possibly 3 UL-Submenus.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone find a suitable solution? I am trying to accomplish the same thing and so far the last solution comes close but it does not add the caret and wanted to know if there was a better solution.

This is what comes close...

```
$('ul li:has(ul)').addClass('dropdown');
$('ul li:has(ul) ul').addClass('dropdown-menu');
$('ul li a:has(ul)').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
$(".dropdown a").attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
$(".dropdown-menu a").removeAttr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
```